# MDC Automatic Instantiation

Tags: mdc-components

I am currently using the "Manual Instantiation" method and it works great.
I noticed the "Automatic Instantiation" method but can't get it to work.
What exactly is needed to use this method?

When I use the code:

```
mdc.tabs.MDCTabBar.attachTo(document.querySelector('#my-mdc-tab-bar'));
```

I get an error logging:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: mdc is not defined".

Reference here:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-tabs#automatic-instantiation

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> **[Material Components Web Docs - Auto Init](https://material.io/develop/web/components/auto-init/)**
>
> `mdc-auto-init` is a utility package that provides declarative,
>   DOM-based method of initialization for MDC Web components on simple
>   web sites. Note that for more advanced use-cases and complex sites,
>   manual instantiation of components will give you more flexibility.
>   However, mdc-auto-init is great for static websites, prototypes, and
>   other use-cases where simplicity and convenience is most appropriate.

When `mdc-auto-init` attaches a component to an element, it assign that instance to the element using a property whose name is the value of `data-mdc-auto-init`. For example, given

```
<div class="mdc-text-field" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextField">
    <input class="mdc-text-field__input" type="text" id="input">
    <label for="input" class="mdc-floating-label">Input Label</label>
    <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
</div>

<!-- at the bottom of the page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.mdc.autoInit();
</script>
```

Once `mdc.autoInit()` is called, you can access the component instance via an MDCTextField property on that element.

Comment: In addition to your answer: if it's a select field, auto init it with `<div class="mdc-select" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCSelect">`

Answer (score 2):

I just had to simply add the whole javascript file MDC package.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@0.36.1/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
```

Only then is the mdc. defined and useable with auto-init.